# Input/output help with a .jar in Java?

Tags: java, jar, io

Feel free to jump to the tl;dr.

This is how my usual experience with my .jar is, in command:

`java -cp test.jar test q a o`
to open the jar

Next, something like
`UF UD UR etc, enter to the program`

This gives me maybe 20 lines of 'response'

I want to do the following:

1 - run the jar using paramaters like above
These parameters should be determined by the GUI (checkboxes, etc, I can do this surely.)

2 - while that .jar is open, submit something along the lines of 
UF UD UR etc, just like before.
These submissions should be determined by the GUI as well.

3 - take the output from that .jar in the background and throw it into a label or something (once it's in a String, I'm good to go. I just need help grabbing it).

Basically:
open jar
input stuff in jar
get output that comes after input
display output.

I've seen a few links related to I/O and I've tried to read up on them, but most of them are questions about this subject, but no working answers.

tl;dr
If someone could please link me to a working example of java I/O with a .jar that runs in command, I would appreciate this immensely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try playing directly with `java.util.JarFile`:

```
JarFile jar = new JarFile( "path to jar" ); // Opens the jar

Enumerator<JarEntry> es = jar.entries(); //Enumerator to the jar entries

while( es.hasMoreElements() ) { //Iterates until all entries have been visited

  JarEntry entry = es.nextElement(); //Gets the next entry in the jar

  System.out.println(  entry.getName() ); //Prints the entry name

  InputStream in = jar.getInputStream( entry ); //returns an inputstream from the entry
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
To be sure:

Line 1 opens the .jar and assigns it to variable 'jar'
Line 2 does...something. I'm not quite sure what, but it seems to assign a number of entries to 'es'? Correct me here.

The while loop stays active until...when exactly?

I'll read up shortly on Enumerators and .nextElement so I understand that bit more.

The input makes sense.

If someone could post a "real-world" example, that would still be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I added more comments in the code example, and corrected a small typo. Enumerators are just old school iterators, without `remove` method. The while loop stays active until all entries have been visited. What do mean by "real-world" ?

Comment: Forget about real-world, actually.  Okay, what does "Enumerator to the jar entries" mean?  Basically: what are .jar 'entries'?  I think after this question, I'll be good to go!

Comment: The 'entries' are the files inside the jar archive. Simply past the code, compile, run, and you'll see.